# Unable to let tour.next() to work on custom element in a vue component

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, bootstrap-tour

I finally completed my app using laravel and vue.js and now I'm trying to set up a Bootstrap Tour to let the users understand what and how they can do, but I'm having a problem breaking my head since yestaerdy. 
So, I set up a bootstrap tour instance in my blade view where I got the vue component `

```
@auth
    @extends ('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <head>
    </head>
    <div  class="container-fluid" id="bladeContainVue">
        <list-medias id="mediasList" :sessions="{{ $allUserSessions }}" :filtersession="{{ json_encode($filterSession) }}" ></list-medias>
    </div>
    <script>

        window.onload = function () {
            // jQuery and everything else is loaded
            // Instance the tour
            var tour = new Tour({
                storage: null,
                steps: [
                    {
                        element: "#mediasList",
                        title: "Your medias",
                        content: "Here we are. Take a look on this page."
                    },
                    {
                        element: ".pendingTour:first",
                        title: "Pending eggs",
                        content: "All the eggs of the chicken are golden."
                    },
                    {
                        element: ".pendingTour:first",
                        reflex: true,
                        title: "Pending eggs/2",
                        content: "Click on colorTheEgg "
                    },
                    {
                        element: "#colorTheEgg",
                        reflex: true,
                        title: "Pending eggs preview",
                        content: ""
                    },

                ]});


            // Initialize the tour
            tour.init();
            // Start the tour
            tour.start();
        }

    </script>


    @endsection
@endauth`
```

Now what my aim is to let pass to the next step of the bootstrap tour when the user click on the button that redirect to a child Vue component, but I can't manange it to work. 
                                                                                    `<img src="/ViewY.png" class="img-fluid inspectElement" v-on:click="openEggManager(userEgg); tour.next(); "`>

If I try with `tour.next();` or `Tour.next(),` I get "tour is undefined" in console, if I do `_this.next();` I got no error but it doesen't go to the next step...

I'm not good at all in JS, I hope there's somebody that can give me a hint on how to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 1):

At the end I solved by myself just by using:

```
// Initialize the tour
            tour.init();
            window.theTourIhave =  tour.start();
```

and the calling it in the child component like this:

```
                    window.theTourIhave.showStep(3);
```

or

```
                window.theTourIhave.next();
```

I hope it can help somebody!